# Victory was not <going to be> easily secured

Tags: meaning, difference

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/secure_1) -> definition #1 -> Extra Examples:
**(1)** *Victory was not going to be easily secured*.
my variant:
**(2)** *Victory was not easily secured*.

I understand (2) but I can't understand (1) because to me, using "*to be going to*" in (1) is strange.

What does "*to be going to*" in (1) mean?
What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

---

Update:

To me (3a) = (3b):
**(3a)** *He says victory **is** not **going to** be easily secured*.
**(3b)** *He says victory **will** not be easily secured*.

To me (4a) = (4b):
**(4a)** *He said victory **was** not **going to** be easily secured*. - "was going to" is the backshifted version of "is going to"
**(4b)** *He said victory **would** not be easily secured*. - "would" is the backshifted version of "will"

But if we remove "he said", backshift disappears:
**(1)** *Victory **was** not **going to** be easily secured*. - now "was going to" is not related to backshift. It means something else that I can't understand.
**(1b)** *Victory **would** not be easily secured*. - now "would" is not related to backshift. That is, "would" here means another thing than just the backshifted version of "will" as in (4b).

Comment: You know what "I am going to [do something]" means? It's about the future. This sentence is looking back at a situation in the past, when people predicted that a contest in _their_ future  would not be easy to win.

Comment: @KateBunting I added an update to my original post to explain in more detail what I can't understand.

Comment: will and going to are not the same meaning. I don't understand why you post more than one question at a time. Why do you?

Comment: @Lambie By drawing the analogy between "_is/was going to_" and "_will/would_", I tried to explain in more detail what I can't understand.

Comment: You're asking more than one question here, or your topic is too broad. Either compare "was going to" with "was"; or compare "is going to" with "will"; or compare "was going to" with "would"; or ask about the meaning of "was going to". Comparing an assortment of arbitrary tenses isn't focused enough.

Comment: To explain my comment in more detail - This could be a sentence from a story. The characters in the story are thinking about something that will soon happen, perhaps a sporting fixture, an election or even a battle. They think "Victory is not going to be easy to secure". However, stories are usually told in the past tense, so the storyteller writes that 'victory **was not** going to be easy to secure' - writing in the past tense about characters looking forward.